# What are the effects of not filling up your active menu completely?

Tags: cook-serve-delicious

You're initially given 4 recipe slots, which is then increased slowly to 5 then 6 as the number of days your restaurant has been operating increases. However, what I would like to know is what happens if you don't fill up your menu. In particular, do the number of customers decrease, or do you simply get the same number of customers ordering other menu items?

Answer (score 2):

This will indirectly have an effect on your customers.

Food items and pairs of food items can affect your buzz. For example, simply having lobster on the menu increases your buzz. This buzz directly influences how many customers you can have.

By not using all the slots you have available for food items, you're limiting your ability to increase your buzz as much as possible. So, nothing bad will happen for having fewer items, but it's still usually advantageous to have a full menu if you can adequately context-switch fast enough to serve 6 different kinds of food.